# Restrict access of managed package custom objects to user

Tags: security, package, packaging

I have created the managed package in that I have some custom object.But I want to give only read access to my one custom object .How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the Debian based systems you can use *install* tool at the install time for that purpose.
Example:
`install -D -m 0444 source destination`
Or if you build Debian package, then the proper way to do that will be using of [package-name.install](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install) files, which executes the same *install* tool.